# QuickFIX/J Error value out of range for this tag

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I've implemented a Java program that uses QuickFIX/J (version 1.6.0). It gets a FIX message (execution report) from the counterparty with the repeating group NoPartyIDs (Tag 453) with following the values

```
(Tag 453) NoPartyIDs = 4

(Tag 447) PartyIDSource = D
(Tag 448) Party ID = XXX
(Tag 452) PartyRole = 1

(Tag 447) PartyIDSource = D
(Tag 448) Party ID = XXX
(Tag 452) PartyRole = 66

(Tag 447) PartyIDSource = D
(Tag 448) Party ID = XXX
(Tag 452) PartyRole = 55
(Tag 802) NoPartySubIDs = 1

(Tag 447) PartyIDSource = D
(Tag 448) Party ID = XXX
(Tag 452) PartyRole = 7
```

Screenshot from this part of the message:
[image]

My program sends automatically an reject message with

```
(Tag 58) Text = "Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag"
(Tag 371) RefTagID = 452
(Tag 373) SessionRejectReason = 5
```

Screentshot from the whole response:
[image]

Now, I am asking me, why my program reacts this way when it received the FIX message. Because the values of the message regarding tag 452 `PartyRole` are not out of range ([look here for the documentation](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/latestEP/en/FIX.5.0SP2_EP194/tag452.html)), or?!

The source file of the QuickFix/J implementation also should know these values.. Here the source:

```
/* Generated Java Source File */
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) quickfixengine.org  All rights reserved. 
 * 
 * This file is part of the QuickFIX FIX Engine 
 * 
 * This file may be distributed under the terms of the quickfixengine.org 
 * license as defined by quickfixengine.org and appearing in the file 
 * LICENSE included in the packaging of this file. 
 * 
 * This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING 
 * THE WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A 
 * PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
 * 
 * See http://www.quickfixengine.org/LICENSE for licensing information. 
 * 
 * Contact ask@quickfixengine.org if any conditions of this licensing 
 * are not clear to you.
 ******************************************************************************/

package quickfix.field;

import quickfix.IntField;


public class PartyRole extends IntField {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;

    public static final int FIELD = 452;
    public static final int EXECUTING_FIRM = 1;
    public static final int BROKER_OF_CREDIT = 2;
    public static final int CLIENT_ID = 3;
    public static final int CLEARING_FIRM = 4;
    public static final int INVESTOR_ID = 5;
    public static final int INTRODUCING_FIRM = 6;
    public static final int ENTERING_FIRM = 7;
    public static final int LOCATE_LENDING_FIRM = 8;
    public static final int FUND_MANAGER_CLIENT_ID = 9;
    public static final int SETTLEMENT_LOCATION = 10;
    public static final int ORDER_ORIGINATION_TRADER = 11;
    public static final int EXECUTING_TRADER = 12;
    public static final int ORDER_ORIGINATION_FIRM = 13;
    public static final int GIVEUP_CLEARING_FIRM = 14;
    public static final int CORRESPONDANT_CLEARING_FIRM = 15;
    public static final int EXECUTING_SYSTEM = 16;
    public static final int CONTRA_FIRM = 17;
    public static final int CONTRA_CLEARING_FIRM = 18;
    public static final int SPONSORING_FIRM = 19;
    public static final int UNDERLYING_CONTRA_FIRM = 20;
    public static final int CLEARING_ORGANIZATION = 21;
    public static final int EXCHANGE = 22;
    public static final int CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT = 24;
    public static final int CORRESPONDENT_CLEARING_ORGANIZATION = 25;
    public static final int CORRESPONDENT_BROKER = 26;
    public static final int BUYER_SELLER = 27;
    public static final int CUSTODIAN = 28;
    public static final int INTERMEDIARY = 29;
    public static final int AGENT = 30;
    public static final int SUB_CUSTODIAN = 31;
    public static final int BENEFICIARY = 32;
    public static final int INTERESTED_PARTY = 33;
    public static final int REGULATORY_BODY = 34;
    public static final int LIQUIDITY_PROVIDER = 35;
    public static final int ENTERING_TRADER = 36;
    public static final int CONTRA_TRADER = 37;
    public static final int POSITION_ACCOUNT = 38;
    public static final int CONTRA_INVESTOR_ID = 39;
    public static final int TRANSFER_TO_FIRM = 40;
    public static final int CONTRA_POSITION_ACCOUNT = 41;
    public static final int CONTRA_EXCHANGE = 42;
    public static final int INTERNAL_CARRY_ACCOUNT = 43;
    public static final int ORDER_ENTRY_OPERATOR_ID = 44;
    public static final int SECONDARY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 45;
    public static final int FORIEGN_FIRM = 46;
    public static final int THIRD_PARTY_ALLOCATION_FIRM = 47;
    public static final int CLAIMING_ACCOUNT = 48;
    public static final int ASSET_MANAGER = 49;
    public static final int PLEDGOR_ACCOUNT = 50;
    public static final int PLEDGEE_ACCOUNT = 51;
    public static final int LARGE_TRADER_REPORTABLE_ACCOUNT = 52;
    public static final int TRADER_MNEMONIC = 53;
    public static final int SENDER_LOCATION = 54;
    public static final int SESSION_ID = 55;
    public static final int ACCEPTABLE_COUNTERPARTY = 56;
    public static final int UNACCEPTABLE_COUNTERPARTY = 57;
    public static final int ENTERING_UNIT = 58;
    public static final int EXECUTING_UNIT = 59;
    public static final int INTRODUCING_BROKER = 60;
    public static final int QUOTE_ORIGINATOR = 61;
    public static final int REPORT_ORIGINATOR = 62;
    public static final int SYSTEMATIC_INTERNALISER = 63;
    public static final int MULTILATERAL_TRADING_FACILITY = 64;
    public static final int REGULATED_MARKET = 65;
    public static final int MARKET_MAKER = 66;
    public static final int INVESTMENT_FIRM = 67;
    public static final int HOST_COMPETENT_AUTHORITY = 68;
    public static final int HOME_COMPETENT_AUTHORITY = 69;
    public static final int COMPETENT_AUTHORITY_OF_THE_MOST_RELEVANT_MARKET_IN_TERMS_OF_LIQUIDITY = 70;
    public static final int COMPETENT_AUTHORITY_OF_THE_TRANSACTION = 71;
    public static final int REPORTING_INTERMEDIARY = 72;
    public static final int EXECUTION_VENUE = 73;
    public static final int MARKET_DATA_ENTRY_ORIGINATOR = 74;
    public static final int LOCATION_ID = 75;
    public static final int DESK_ID = 76;
    public static final int MARKET_DATA_MARKET = 77;
    public static final int ALLOCATION_ENTITY = 78;

    public PartyRole() {
        super(452);
    }

    public PartyRole(int data) {
        super(452, data);
    }

}
```

Maybe you had a similiar problem or you see my fallacy..

Thank you for your help dudes!!!

Comment: Are you using `DataDictionary` and the proper configs ? Are these values defined in your DataDictionary ? Same issue here it seems http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/Value-is-incorrect-out-of-range-for-this-tag-371-35-td3050411.html

Comment: hey! Yes, I am using a `DataDictionary`. The message definition contains a `<component name="Parties" required="N"/>` and this is the field which causes the problems. But the range of its values aren't defined in this xml-file but in the Java file, or?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a field `PartyRole=66` in the ExecutionReport, which is not a valid value for the [PartyRole in FIX 4.4](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.4.4/tag452.html) (your reject message has `8=FIX.4.4`). The documentation link you post is for FIX 5.0 SP2.

If your counterparty is sending PartyRole values that are not supported in FIX 4.4, you might consider creating a separate Data Dictionary to support them for this particular counterparty.

Comment: Changed the link to FIXIMATE 4.4 link instead of OnixBiz link to PartyRole.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!!! I am using the field in version 4.4 but the counterparty sends it in version 5.0! The different possible values in both versions regarding the tag 452 cause the problem!

Comment: @mrbela I suppose you will try to create a seperate Data Dictionary for this counterparty?

Comment: Yes. I've downloaded the standard DataDictionary (FIX 4.4 xml from http://quickfixengine.org/) and now I am customizing this one.. Most of the messages I recieve from the counterparty are in FIX 4.4, sometimes fields from 5.0.. So 4.4 is the best version to customize.. Isn't that a propper way?

Comment: @mrbela I've never had to edit a Data Dictionary so I have no experience there. I did read about people having to edit their DD for custom tags. I think it would be best to create a seperate DD based on the 4.4 DD. So you're doing it right as far as I can tell.

Comment: I really have to wonder why two people gave this answer -1 when I clearly got the right answer. Would those people want to give at least an explanation why they downvoted?

Comment: I'm very surprised that you've never modified a DD before, @TT.  I've done it for every single FIX project I've been a part of.  In fact, I recommend doing that and regenerating the source based on it.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I've only been involved in one FIX project with one counterparty and so far tweaking the DD has not been necessary for me. I am however interested in FIX/QuickFIX so I research a lot of things. If I get around to it I will certainly try it so that I have that experience.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, too!! The answer was EXACT the right one and to find the problem was for sure a bit tricky.. Nice work @TT and thanks again for your help!

Comment: Downvotes are random and sometimes loosers go around downvoting wherever they want, without any plausible reason.